# Django syncdb exception after updating to 1.4

Tags: django, updating, django-syncdb

So I was developing an app in Django and needed a function from the 1.4 version so I decided to update.
But then a weird error appeared when I wanted to do `syncdb`
I am using the new `manage.py` and as You can see it makes some of the tables but then fails :

```
./manage.py syncdb
Creating tables ...
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table auth_user_groups
Creating table auth_user
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table django_session
Creating table django_site
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 9, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 91, in handle_noargs
    sql, references = connection.creation.sql_create_model(model, self.style,     seen_models)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/creation.py", line 44, in sql_create_model
    col_type = f.db_type(connection=self.connection)
TypeError: db_type() got an unexpected keyword argument 'connection'
```

Comment: I found that the error was caused by a custom EnumField that I was using  (for all those that will have the same error)

Comment: Thanks for following up your question :)

Comment: What did you do to overcome this? Did you modify your `EnumField` class? If so, what did you do?

Comment: I erased the field after reading that a MySQL database doesent support it. I added a smallIntegerField with choice options: 
`models.SmallIntegerField(choices=PLATFORM_CHOICES, blank=True, default=5)`
`PLATFORM_CHOICES=(
  (1, 'iOS'),
  (2, 'MAC'),
  (3, 'iPhone'),
  (4, 'iPad'),
  (5, 'Universal'),
 )`

Comment: @JakubSzymion Should post an answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, the definition for my custom field was missing the connection parameter.

```
from django.db import models

class BigIntegerField(models.IntegerField):
    def db_type(self, connection):
        return "bigint"
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Although already old, answered and accepted question but I am adding my understanding I have added it because I am not using customized type and it is a Django Evolution error (but not syncdb)`evolve --hint --execute`. I think it may be helpful for someone in future. .</sub>

I am average in Python and new to Django. I also encounter same issue when I added some new features to my existing project. To add new feature I had to add some new fields of `models.CharField()` type,as follows.

```
included_domains = models.CharField(
     "set of comma(,) seprated list of domains in target emails", 
     default="",           
     max_length=it_len.EMAIL_LEN*5) 
excluded_domains = models.CharField(
    "set of comma(,) seprated list of domains NOT in target emails", 
    default="",               
    max_length=it_len.EMAIL_LEN*5)
```

The Django version I am using is 1.3.1:

```
$ python -c "import django; print django.get_version()"
1.3.1  <--------# version  

$python manage.py syncdb
Project signature has changed - an evolution is required
```

[Django Evolution:](https://code.google.com/p/django-evolution/#Django_Evolution) Django Evolution is an extension to Django that allows you to track changes in your models over time, and to update the database to reflect those changes.

```
$ python manage.py evolve --hint 
#----- Evolution for messagingframework
from django_evolution.mutations import AddField
from django.db import models


MUTATIONS = [
    AddField('MessageConfiguration', 'excluded_domains', models.CharField, initial=u'', max_length=300),
    AddField('MessageConfiguration', 'included_domains', models.CharField, initial=u'', max_length=300)
]
#----------------------
Trial evolution successful.
Run './manage.py evolve --hint --execute' to apply evolution.
```

The trial was susses and when I tried to apply changes in DB

```
$ python manage.py evolve --hint --execute
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 25, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/var/www/sites/www.taxspanner.com/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 362, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/var/www/sites/www.taxspanner.com/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 303, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/var/www/sites/www.taxspanner.com/django/core/management/base.py", line 195, in run_from_argv  
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/var/www/sites/www.taxspanner.com/django/core/management/base.py", line 222, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_evolution-0.6.9.dev_r225-py2.7.egg/django_evolution/management/commands/evolve.py", line 60, in handle
    self.evolve(*app_labels, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_evolution-0.6.9.dev_r225-py2.7.egg/django_evolution/management/commands/evolve.py", line 140, in evolve
    database))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_evolution-0.6.9.dev_r225-py2.7.egg/django_evolution/mutations.py", line 426, in mutate
    return self.add_column(app_label, proj_sig, database)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_evolution-0.6.9.dev_r225-py2.7.egg/django_evolution/mutations.py", line 438, in add_column
    sql_statements = evolver.add_column(model, field, self.initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_evolution-0.6.9.dev_r225-py2.7.egg/django_evolution/db/common.py", line 142, in add_column
    f.db_type(connection=self.connection),  # <===  here f is field class object
TypeError: db_type() got an unexpected keyword argument 'connection'
```

To understand this exception I check that this exception is something similar to:

```
>>> def f(a):
...  print a
... 
>>> f('b', b='a')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'b'
>>>
```

So the function signature has been changed.

Because I have not added any *new customized or enum* fields but only two similar fields that was already in model and char type field is supported by most of database (I am ussing PostgreSQL) even I was getting this error!

Then I read from @: [Russell Keith-Magee-4 Reply](http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/Django-1-4-TypeError-get-db-prep-value-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-connection-td4695088.html).

> What you've hit here is the end of the deprecation cycle for code that
>   doesn't support multiple databases.
>
> In Django 1.2, we introduced multiple database support; in order to
>   support this, the prototype for `get_db_preb_lookup()` and
>   `get_db_prep_value()` was changed.
>
> For backwards compatibility, we added a shim that would transparently
>   'fix' these methods if they hadn't already been fixed by the
>   developer.
>
> In Django 1.2, the usage of these shims raised a
>   PendingDeprecationWarning. In Django 1.3, they raised a
>   DeprecationWarning.
>
> Under Django 1.4, the shim code was been removed -- so any code that
>   wasn't updated will now raise errors like the one you describe.

But I am not getting any DeprecationWarning warning assuming because of newer version of Django Evolution.

But from above quote I could understand that to support multiple databases function signature is added and an extra argument `connection` is needed. I also check the `db_type()` signature in my installation of Django as follows:

```
/django$ grep --exclude-dir=".svn" -n 'def db_type(' * -R 
contrib/localflavor/us/models.py:8:    def db_type(self):
contrib/localflavor/us/models.py:24:    def db_type(self):
   :
   :
```

Ialso refer of Django documentation

> #### [Field.db_type(self, connection):](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#django.db.models.Field.db_type)
>
> Returns the *database column data type for the Field*, taking into account the connection
>   object, and the settings associated with it.

And Then I could understand that to resolve this issue  I have to inherited `models.filed` class and overwrite `def db_type()` function. And because I am using [PostgreSQL in which to create 300 chars type field](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-character.html) I need to return `'char(300)'`.   In my models.py I added:

```
class CharMaxlengthN(models.Field):
    def db_type(self, connection):
        return 'char(%d)' % self.max_length  # because I am using postgresql
```

<sup>If you encounter similar problem please check your underline DB's manual that which type of column you need to create and return a string.</sup>

And changed the definition of new fields (that I need to add) read comments:

```
included_domains = CharMaxlengthN( # <--Notice change 
      "set of comma(,) seprated list of domains in target emails", 
      default="",           
      max_length=it_len.EMAIL_LEN*5) 
excluded_domains = CharMaxlengthN( # <-- Notice change
     "set of comma(,) seprated list of domains NOT in target emails", 
     default="",               
     max_length=it_len.EMAIL_LEN*5)
```

Then I executed same command that was failing previously:

```
t$ python manage.py evolve --hint --execute

You have requested a database evolution. This will alter tables
and data currently in the None database, and may result in
IRREVERSABLE DATA LOSS. Evolutions should be *thoroughly* reviewed
prior to execution.

Are you sure you want to execute the evolutions?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
Evolution successful.
```

I also check my DB and tested my new added features It is now working perfectly, and no DB problem.

If you wants to create ENUM field read [`Specifying a mySQL ENUM in a Django model`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19040441/1673391).

**Edit:** I realized instead of sub classing `models.Field` I should have inherit more specific subclass that is `models.CharField`.

Similarly I need to create Decimal DB fields so I added following class in model:

```
class DecimalField(models.DecimalField):
    def db_type(self, connection):
        d = {
            'max_digits': self.max_digits,
            'decimal_places': self.decimal_places,
        } 
        return 'numeric(%(max_digits)s, %(decimal_places)s)' % d
```