# How to manage Postgres Enum type in Django?

Tags: django, postgresql, enums

I had used [django-mysql](https://pypi.org/project/django-mysql/) to manage MySQL enum type from Django. Recently I am using the Postgres database for my Django project. To manage the [Postgres Enum](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html), I could not able to find any library. There is a [db_type()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.db_type) method in Django to manage custom type. But the problem is Postgres enum must be created first at database and after that, I can use it.

Here is a code sample for Postgres enum.

```
CREATE TYPE mood AS ENUM ('sad', 'ok', 'happy');
CREATE TABLE person (
    name text,
    current_mood mood
);
```

Is there present a library at all?
If not, how could I be able to achieve the Postgres enum management from Django?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if the schema is pre-baked then just [defining the same choices and pretending the field is text-valued](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13089465/148926) does work. Have tested this just now with Postgresql 13.3 and Django 3.2.6 / psycopg2 2.9.1 .

Otherwise I've seen other people doing magic with custom database schema management -- [here](https://schinckel.net/2019/09/18/postgres-enum-types-in-django/) and [here](https://github.com/AlexanderTar/django-more/tree/master/django_enum).